# Web Navigation Bar Will Not Center

Tags: html, css

Trying to get the words in my navigation bar to center. I have tried a bunch of different configs that I found online and so far no luck.

Also, is there anything I can do to make the navigation bar appear cleaner and more professional?

Thank you in advance

```
 <div class="nav-container clearfix">
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="first"><a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>"><span>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>whysoy"><span>Why Soy?</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>plantatree"><span>Candle Sold, Tree Planted</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>build-a-candle.html"><span>Build-a-Candle</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>contact-us"><span>Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a class="category" href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>all-products">
            <span>Buy Products</span>
            <ul class="level0">
                <?php echo $_menu ?>

            </ul>
        </a>
    </li>


</ul>
```

```
/*** CLEARFIX ******/

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
 clear: both
  }
/********** < Navigation */
.nav-container {clear: both; width:100%; float: left; text-align: center; margin: 10px 0px 10px; text-transform:     uppercase; font-weight: bold; display: inline; background:#d4dadd !important; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888     !important; } 
#nav { margin:0 auto; padding:0; font-size:12px; }

/* All Levels */ /* Style consistent throughout all nav levels */
#nav li {
display: inline-block;
padding: 5px;
margin: 5px;
border-right: 1px solid #000;
list-style: none;
vertical-align: top;
height: 50px;
position:relative;
}

#nav li.over { z-index:998; background-color: #b3bec3; }
#nav a,
#nav a:hover { display:block; line-height:1.3em; text-decoration:none; padding: 10px;
text-align: center; } 
#nav span { display:block; cursor:pointer; }
#nav li ul span {white-space:normal; }
#nav ul li.parent a {}
#nav ul li.parent li a { background-image:none; }
#nav a.category span { background: url(../images/nav-category.gif) no-repeat center right; padding-right:  20px; }

/* 0 Level */
#nav li.active a { color:#2882ce; }
#nav a { font-size: 115%; color:#303030; }
#nav li.last a { padding-right: 0px !important;}
#nav li.over a,
#nav a:hover { color:#2882ce; }

/* 1st Level */
#nav ul li,
#nav ul li.active { float:none; margin:0; padding-bottom:1px; background:#d4dadd; }
#nav ul li.last { background:#d4dadd; padding-bottom:0; }

#nav ul a,
#nav ul a:hover { float:none; padding:0; background:none; }
#nav ul li a { font-size: 100% !important; font-weight:normal !important; }

/* 2nd Level */
#nav ul,
#nav div { position:absolute; width:15em; top:27px; left:-10000px; border:1px solid #899ba5; }
#nav div ul { position:static; width:auto; border:none; }

/* 3rd+ Level */
#nav ul ul,
#nav ul div { top:5px; }

#nav ul li a { background:#d4dadd;  }
#nav ul li a:hover { background:#b3bec3; }
#nav ul li a,
#nav ul li a:hover { color:#2f2f2f !important; }
#nav ul span,
#nav ul li.last li span { padding:3px 15px 4px 15px; }

/* Show menu */
#nav li ul.shown-sub,
#nav li div.shown-sub { left:0; z-index:999; }
#nav li .shown-sub ul.shown-sub,
#nav li .shown-sub li div.shown-sub { left:100px; }

<div class="nav-container clearfix">
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="first"><a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>"><span>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>whysoy"><span>Why Soy?</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>plantatree"><span>Candle Sold, Tree Planted</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>build-a-candle.html"><span>Build-a-Candle</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>contact-us"><span>Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a class="category" href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>all-products">
            <span>Buy Products</span>
            <ul class="level0">
                <?php echo $_menu ?>

            </ul>
        </a>
    </li>


</ul>
```

Comment: add some `width` here: `#nav { margin:0 auto; padding:0; font-size:12px; }`

Comment: @dippas adding width to that line made the list change to verticle instead of horizontal. I put in the 'display: inline' to make it one line. This made the width variable invalid, as in every number I change it to, it will not change the nav.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code a bit, here is a snippet below, to see this snippet working click Full Page button.

**UPDATED snippet** based on OP's Comments to answer.


```css
/*** CLEARFIX ******/

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both
}
/********** < Navigation */

.nav-container {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline;
  background: #ecf3f6 !important;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888 !important;
}
#nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}
/* All Levels */

/* Style consistent throughout all nav levels */

#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  list-style: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 70px;
  width:16.3%
}
#nav li:last-child {
  border-right: 0
}
#nav li.over {
  z-index: 998;
  background-color: #d4dadd;
}
#nav a,
#nav a:hover {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center
}
#nav span {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer
}
#nav li ul span {
  white-space: normal;
}
#nav ul li.parent a {} #nav ul li.parent li a {
  background-image: none;
}
#nav a.category span {
  background: url(../images/nav-category.gif) no-repeat center right;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
/* 0 Level */

#nav li.active a {
  color: #2882ce;
}
#nav a {
  font-size: 115%;
  color: #303030;
}
#nav li.last a {
  padding-right: 0px !important;
}
#nav li.over a,
#nav a:hover {
  color: #2882ce;
}
/* 1st Level */

#nav ul li,
#nav ul li.active {
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  background: #ecf3f6;
}
#nav ul li.last {
  background: #ecf3f6;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
#nav ul a,
#nav ul a:hover {
  float: none;
  padding: 0;
  background: none;
}
#nav ul li a {
  font-size: 100% !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
}
/* 2nd Level */

#nav ul,
#nav div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 15em;
  top: 27px;
  left: -10000px;
  border: 1px solid #899ba5;
}
#nav div ul {
  position: static;
  width: auto;
  border: none;
}
/* 3rd+ Level */

#nav ul ul,
#nav ul div {
  top: 5px;
}
#nav ul li a {
  background: #ecf3f6;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
  background: #d5e4eb;
}
#nav ul li a,
#nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #2f2f2f !important;
}
#nav ul span,
#nav ul li.last li span {
  padding: 3px 15px 4px 15px;
}
/* Show menu */

#nav li ul.shown-sub,
#nav li div.shown-sub {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}
#nav li .shown-sub ul.shown-sub,
#nav li .shown-sub li div.shown-sub {
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-container clearfix">
  <ul id="nav">
    <li class="first"><a href=""><span>Home</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">whysoy<span>Why Soy?</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">plantatree<span>Candle Sold, Tree Planted</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""><span>Build-a-Candle</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""><span>Contact Us</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="category" href=""><span>Buy Products</span>
          <ul class="level0">
          </ul>
           </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**UPDATE #3** (with new info from OP)

in order to achieve what you want, just make this changes below on your CSS:

```
.nav-container {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #d4dadd !important;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888 !important;
  float: left;
  font-size: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
}
#nav li {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 15%;
}
#nav ul li, #nav ul li.active {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #d4dadd;
  border-right: 0 none;
  display: block;
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
/*you may delete this:
     #nav ul li.last {

}*/
```

Comment: Doing this now makes the nav bars background capture the top of the page and logo. Also, when you go to the dropdown, it puts it in the top left of the page. The words are still not centered.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you want.. do you want the nav centered as this is or do you want only the list items of nav centered and keeping the nav as it was before?

Comment: I want the words to be centered in the buttons. As of right now, you hover and the words are all aligned left with space on the right.

Comment: ok, but want to keep the the old nav (yours) or want to stay with the new one (mine) ?

Comment: the old nav is what I want. I also want the left and right of the whole bar rounded and each button have a divider.

Comment: Anyway to make the buttons equal so there are not any unused spaces on the right and left of the nav bar? Anyway to get rid of the right most line break? Also, the dropdown box is centered when the words should be on the left. In that box, it is not filled in.

Comment: hold on, let me see if I'm doing what you want. I'll update my answer asap

Comment: still not working. I added the code I am currently using. The dropdown still isnt right and adding the nav li width messed everything up

Comment: I can't help much more unless you show me whole html code with drop menu and all... because these one doesn't have anything. are you able to do that? or may be show the link to the site?